# Mapper and reduceByKey

Tags: python, computer-science, google-colaboratory

I am in the process of creating a bloom filter and need to generate a mapper to map each indices inside the in_trenches variable to 1 and use reduceByKey to remove index duplicates and sort them. Does anyone know how to properly do each step? This is the coding that I used.

```
# generate a mapper to map each indices inside in_trenches variable to 1.
 mapper = in_trenches.map(indice, 1)

# Use reduceByKey to remove index duplicates (d) and sort them
 remove_duplicates = mapper.reduceByKey(lambda x, y:(x))
```